# source filename not working

Tags: sql, mysql

i am trying to run a sql file with this code:

```
source filename.sql
```

and it says failed to open file

Comment: Where, wich OS, app, user privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what application? What OS?

You might try `./filename.sql` instead if you're on a nix box.

Permissions might also be an issue.

More information would be gratefully received.